# How to update data in Firestore monthly?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Firestore database, each user has some limits on certain actions. I need to make sure that every first day these limits are updated in my database for all users. I've heard about "Firebase Cloud Functions", but I haven't figured out how to use them to implement my functionality.
Please tell me how it is possible to implement periodic data updates in Firebase Firestore?

I can update data from the application itself using global time, but then the code will only run when the application is opened, so it must be a server solution.

Answer (score 1):

To implement periodic data updates in Firebase Firestore, you can indeed use Firebase Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions allow you to run server-side code in response to events and triggers, such as scheduled intervals. You can set up a scheduled function to run every day and update the limits for all users in your Firestore database.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how you can implement this functionality:

1. Set up your Firebase project: If you haven't already, create a Firebase project in the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/).
2. Install Firebase CLI: Install the Firebase Command Line Interface (CLI) by following the instructions in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli.
3. Initialize Cloud Functions: In your project directory, open a terminal or command prompt and run the following command to initialize Cloud Functions:
4. Write the scheduled function: Open the generated index.js file located in the functions directory. This file contains the code for your Cloud Functions.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.updateLimits = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun((context) => {
    // Get all users from Firestore
    return firestore.collection('users').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const promises = [];

            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                // Update the limits for each user
                const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(doc.id);
                promises.push(userRef.update({ limits: /* new limits object */ }));
            });

            // Wait for all updates to complete
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error updating limits:', error);
        });
});
```